# Facing problem in forwarding traffic on port 2222 to docker 172.17.0.2 :22

Tags: iptables, docker

None of the below commands works please help!

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.26.7.222 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:22
sudo iptables -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o docker0 --source 0.0.0.0/0 --destination 172.17.0.2 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -t nat -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 --source 0.0.0.0/0 --destination 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --dport 2222  -j DNAT --to 172.17.0.2:22
sudo iptables -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o docker0 --source 0.0.0.0/0 --destination 172.17.0.2 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

This works seamlessly -

```
 sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to 172.17.0.2:22
 sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.17.0.2 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```